# What happens when a bounty expires?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Okay so someone put a bounty of $201336200 on me. If I never get killed what will happen with the money? Will I get the money or will the bounty stay on me?

Comment: @SteveV. surely this is a totally different question?

Comment: @shanodin - Tonyy asked what happened if he didn't get killed. To me that's the same as losing a bounty.

Comment: I was basically asking what happens with the money If I lose a bounty

Comment: Dude gimme da monne plz!!

Answer (score 2):

If you outlive the bounty - a full in-game day (48 minutes real time) - you will receive the cash.